# Error when scaping string (php - postgres)

Tags: php, postgresql, stored-procedures, escaping

I'm trying to escape a string using PHP to make a query to postgres but I allways get an error.

```
SELECT some.sp( '1', '{0}', '{ aa \'\' \"\" .. ,,, ;; -- //}');
```

error:

```
syntax error at or near "\" LINE x: '
```

I used addslashes() and pg_escape_string() but... nothing...

DEBUG

```
echo $_POST["xx"]; 
echo pg_escape_bytea($_POST["xx"]);
echo pg_escape_string($_POST["xx"]);


result: xAAA '' "" .. ,,, ;; -- // 
result: xAAA '''' "" .. ,,, ;; -- // 
result: xAAA '''' "" .. ,,, ;; -- //
```

Comment: But why don't you use prepared statements instead? Manual escaping is very dangerous. And possibly wrong in your case: [for a while, PostgreSQL follows the ANSI convention for escaping](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS), like: `'string with escaped '' single quote'`

Comment: The old syntax is available when you turn `standard_conforming_strings` to `off`, or use the special, PostgreSQL specific syntax: `E'\''`